# version problem in hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, alchemy

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

// Returns the ether balance of a given address.
async function getBalance(address) {
  const balanceBigInt = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
  return hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceBigInt);
}

// Logs the Ether balances for a list of addresses.
async function printBalances(addresses) {
  let index = 0;
  for (const address of addresses) {
    console.log(`Addresses ${index} balance: `, await getBalance(address));
    index++;
  }
}

// Logs the memos stored on-chain from coffee purchases.
async function printMemos(memos) {
  for (const memo of memos) {
    const timestamp = memo.timestamp;
    const tipper = memo.name;
    const tipperAddress = memo.from;
    const message = memo.message;
    console.log(`At ${timestamp}, ${tipper} (${tipperAddress}) said: "${message}"`);
  }
}
console.log("2");
async function main() {
  // Get the example accounts we'll be working with.
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("3");
  const BuyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('BuyMeACoffee');
  const buyMeACoffee = await BuyMeACoffee.deploy();
  console.log("4");
  // Deploy the contract.
  await buyMeACoffee.deployed();
  console.log("6");
  console.log("BuyMeACoffee deployed to:", buyMeACoffee.address);
  console.log("5");
  // Check balances before the coffee purchase.
  const addresses = [owner.address, tipper.address, buyMeACoffee.address];
  console.log("== start ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Buy the owner a few coffees.
  const tip = { value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1") };
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Rahul", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Suprit", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper3).buyCoffee("Prasad", "You're a good coder", tip);

  // Check balances after the coffee purchase.
  console.log("== bought coffee ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Withdraw.
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(owner).withdrawTips();

  // Check balances after withdrawal.
  //console.log("== withdrawTips ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Check out the memos.
  console.log("== memos ==");
  const memos = await buyMeACoffee.getMemos();
  printMemos(memos);

}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

`TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.3) at makeError ) { code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', argument: 'key', value: 'deployed' }`

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.17.0"
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the changes in hardhat-tools 3.0.0.
Make the following changes

- **deploy => deployContract - directly pass the contract name and not the factory**.
- **deployed => waitForDeployment**

Your main function would look like:

```
    async function main() {
  // Get the example accounts we'll be working with.
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("3");
  const BuyMeACoffee = await 
  const buyMeACoffee = await ethers.deployContract("BuyMeACoffee");
  console.log("4");
  // Deploy the contract.
  await buyMeACoffee.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("6");
  console.log("BuyMeACoffee deployed to:", buyMeACoffee.address);
  console.log("5");
  // Check balances before the coffee purchase.
  const addresses = [owner.address, tipper.address, buyMeACoffee.address];
  console.log("== start ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Buy the owner a few coffees.
  const tip = { value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1") };
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Rahul", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Suprit", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper3).buyCoffee("Prasad", "You're a good coder", tip);

  // Check balances after the coffee purchase.
  console.log("== bought coffee ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Withdraw.
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(owner).withdrawTips();

  // Check balances after withdrawal.
  //console.log("== withdrawTips ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Check out the memos.
  console.log("== memos ==");
  const memos = await buyMeACoffee.getMemos();
  printMemos(memos);

}
```

Comment: showing the same error.

Comment: Check the ethers version and update or downgrade accordingly.

Comment: using the latest version of ethers but still not working.

Comment: How can it be the same error when you're not using deployed word any more?

Comment: yeah, that issue is solved but now it's showing -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatEther')

Comment: Trying using ethers without hre once. Also if my answer resolved your issue then please mark it as the answer.

Comment: removing hre didn't work. It shows TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatEther')

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.deployed()` with `.waitForDeployment()` - These updates result from hardhat-tools 3.0.0 changes.

Comment: still showing the same error.